# Restoring a 2 gb sql server database is taking hours , using command t-sql code too

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-backups

So I tried restoring a .bak of sql with SSMS wizard and it seemed to have be hanging.  I blew it away.  I read some stackoverflow answers to other people along with some blogs so i decided to do it a a query

It is still churning for hours on a 2 GB bak file ,  Does this code seem ok?

```
USE master;  
GO  

RESTORE DATABASE Spark  
  FROM DISK =   'F:\backups\Spark_backup_2017_03_26_020006_3893816\Spark_backup_2017_03_26_020006_3893816.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,  
  MOVE 'Spark' TO 'F:\Data\Spark.mdf',   
  MOVE 'Spark_Log' TO 'F:\Log\Spark_log.ldf';  
GO
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, It finished with these messages 
Anything that looks bad?

```
Processed 262248 pages for database 'Spark', file 'Spark' on file 1.
Processed 8 pages for database 'Spark', file 'Spark_log' on file 1.
Converting database 'Spark' from version 661 to the current version 852.
Database 'Spark' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version 668.
```

It goes on the repeat that last line many times increasing in the version #

Then final 2 lines

```
Database 'Spark' running the upgrade step from version 851 to version 852.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 262256 pages in 4533.296 seconds (0.451 MB/sec).
```

Comment: You can use the `stats` switch to see a restore progress: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/

Comment: Hi,  @Nick.McDermaid    thx,   It finished before I got a chance to run that..  Any thoughts on my Update section ?

Comment: No that all looks fine. Looks like you are are restoring an older version database backup into a newer version. Consider changing the compatability level (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41543599/how-to-adjust-compatibility-level-after-database-restore) and running a statistics update. Read this about some smart things to do after a database upgrade: https://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check/

Comment: You might find that if you backup and restore out of this database it will be quicker because it doesn't have to upgrade. Version 661 is SQL 2008 R2 but I don't know what version 852 is. SQL 2016 I guess.

Comment: oh, i see,   problem is taking old versions and backing them onto azure for an upcoming physical move    -  thx